# master slave Database configuration not working spring boot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, master-slave

I want to implement master slave DB artitechure in my spring boot application and I am just using 2 normal DB instances,Havent configured something at DB level,I have listed down my configuration and error below,Can someone help? Do something config needs to be done at db level as I am just testing.Please let me know.

Heres my DataSourceConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig extends HikariConfig {

    @Value("${spring.entity.scan.packages}")
    private String packageToScan;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.master.url}")
    private String masterDbUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.master.username}")
    private String masterDbUserName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.master.password}")
    private String masterDbPassword;

    @Value("${master.database.maxconnection}")
    private int masterDbMaxConnection;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.slave.url}")
    private String slaveDbUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.slave.username}")
    private String slaveDbUserName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.slave.password}")
    private String slaveDbPassword;

    @Value("${master.database.maxconnection}")
    private int slaveDbMaxConnection;



    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        HikariConfig masterConfig = new HikariConfig();
        masterConfig.setPoolName(DataSourceConfig.class.getName()+"_master");
        System.out.println(masterDbUrl);
        System.out.println(masterDbUserName);
        System.out.println(masterDbPassword);
        System.out.println(masterDbMaxConnection);
        masterConfig.setJdbcUrl(masterDbUrl);
        masterConfig.setUsername(masterDbUserName);
        masterConfig.setPassword(masterDbPassword);
        masterConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(masterDbMaxConnection);
        return new HikariDataSource(masterConfig);
    }

    @Bean(name = "slaveDataSource")
    public DataSource slaveDataSource() {
        HikariConfig slaveConfig = new HikariConfig();
        slaveConfig.setPoolName(DataSourceConfig.class.getName()+"_slave");
        System.out.println(slaveDbUrl);
        System.out.println(slaveDbUserName);
        System.out.println(slaveDbPassword);
        System.out.println(slaveDbMaxConnection);
        slaveConfig.setJdbcUrl(slaveDbUrl);
        slaveConfig.setUsername(slaveDbUserName);
        slaveConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(slaveDbMaxConnection);
        slaveConfig.setPassword(slaveDbPassword);
        return new HikariDataSource(slaveConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource routingDataSource() {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        RoutingDataSourceConfiguration routingDataSourceConfiguration = new RoutingDataSourceConfiguration();
        DataSource master = this.masterDataSource();
        targetDataSources.put(DataSourceTypes.MASTER, master);
        DataSource slave = this.slaveDataSource();
        targetDataSources.put(DataSourceTypes.SLAVE, slave);
        routingDataSourceConfiguration.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        routingDataSourceConfiguration.setDefaultTargetDataSource(master);
        return routingDataSourceConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(routingDataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(packageToScan);
        JpaVendorAdapter vendor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendor);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager
            (EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return tm;
    }


}
```

Here's my RoutingDataSourceConfiguration:

```
public class RoutingDataSourceConfiguration extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        boolean isReadOnly = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();
        logger.info(isReadOnly);
        if(isReadOnly) {
            return DataSourceTypes.SLAVE;
        } else {
            return DataSourceTypes.MASTER;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my application.properties:

```
database.db.name=db_delivery
spring.datasource.master.url=jdbc:mysql://171.46.7.224/${database.db.name}?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.master.username=user
spring.datasource.master.password=pass
spring.datasource.master.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.slave.url=jdbc:mysql://171.43.7.214/${database.db.name}?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.slave.username=user
spring.datasource.slave.password=pass
spring.datasource.slave.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
master.database.maxconnection=100
spring.entity.scan.packages=com.project

server.port=8080

spring.security.user.name=System
spring.security.user.password=pass
```

Here's my repo:

```
@Repository
public interface JobsCycleCountRepo extends JpaRepository<JobsCycleCount,Long>  {

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  List<WarehouseJobsCycleCount> findAllByJobId(Long jobId);
}
```

Here's my entity WarehouseJobsCycleCount:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "warehouse_jobs_cycle_count")
@Data
public class WarehouseJobsCycleCount {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "job_id")
  private Long jobId;

  @Column(name = "sku_id")
  private String skuId;

  @Column(name = "location_id")
  private Long locationId;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private WarehouseJobCycleCountStatus status;

}
```

Now when I call this repo method via any service method through a controller,I get an error like this:

```
SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2023-04-27 14:53:40.919 ERROR 10375 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'warehousej0_.jobId' in 'field list'
2023-04-27 14:53:41.060 ERROR 10375 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.d.w.exceptions.ControllerAdvisor       : Custom Exception: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
2023-04-27 14:53:42.256  WARN 10375 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]
```

How to solve this? I have been stuck on this since 2 days but nothing is working.